# Kazhdan-Lusztig equivalence for Lie super-algebras

Tags: quantum-groups, kac-moody-algebras, lie-superalgebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a semi-simple Lie algebra. Kazhdan and Lusztig studied the category of representations of the corresponding affine Lie algebra (the central extension of $\mathfrak g((t))$) which are  integrable under $\mathfrak g[[t]]$; under some assumptions on the central charge they constructed a tensor structure there and proved that the resulting tensor category is equivalent to the category of finite-dimensional representations of the corresponding quantum group (where the parameter $q$ in the quantum group depends on the central charge).

My question is the following: is there a known analog of these results for Lie super-algebras? I am particularly interested in $\mathfrak g=\text{gl}(m|n)$. Have people studied the Kazhdan-Lusztig category for Lie super-algebras?

Answer (score 4):

In: [Kazhdan-Lustzig polynomials and character formulae for the Lie superalgebra $gl(m|n)$](http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/2003-16-01/S0894-0347-02-00408-3/S0894-0347-02-00408-3.pdf), J. Amer. Math. Soc. 16 (2002), 185–231, J. Brundan develops a conjecture on the characters for the irreducible modules and tilting modules in the full
BGG category $\mathcal{O}^{m|n}$ of $gl(m|n)$ modules.

In: [The Brundan–Kazhdan–Lusztig conjecture for general linear Lie superalgebras](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1426512104), Duke Math. J. Volume 164, Number 4 (2015), 617-695 and in:
[Tensor Product Categorifications and the Super Kazhdan–Lusztig Conjecture](https://academic.oup.com/imrn/article/2017/20/6329/3061017), , IMRN, Volume 2017, Issue 20, 1 October 2017, Pages 6329–6410, independent proofs are provided.
(see also: [this paper](https://darkwing.uoregon.edu/~brundan/papers/supero.pdf))

(The arXiv versions are: [arXiv:1203.0092 [math.RT]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1203.0092) and [arXiv:1310.0349v3 [math.RT]](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.0349) correspondingly).

I am not a specialist to say more, but i think the results in these papers may be related to what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed related although not exactly the same